# I don't understand how to create and use dynamic arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay so I have;

```
int grid_x = 5
int * grid;
grid = new int[grid_x];
*grid = 34;
cout << grid[0];
```

Should line 3 create an array with 5 elements? Or fill the first element with the number 5?

Line 4 fills the first element, how do I fill the rest?

Without line 4, line 5 reads "-842150451".

I don't understand what is going on, I'm trying to create a 2 dimensional array using x and y values specified by the user, and then fill each element one by one with numeric values also specified by the user. My above code was an attempt to try it out with a 1 dimensional array first.

Comment: _"Should line 3 create an array with 5 elements?"_ Yes. _"Or fill the first element with the number 5?"_ No.

Comment: "Without line 4, line 5 reads "-842150451"." Yes, because the array point somewhere in the memory that is not initialized! It can be any value unless you initialize it with line 4 :)

Comment: Just a little and barely important addition. Decimal `-842150451` is a hexadecimal `0xCDCDCDCD`. That's how Visual Studio's debug runtime indicates uninitialized memory and helps programmers to find memory bugs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should line 3 create an array with 5 elements?

Yes. It won't initialise them though, which is why you see a weird value.

> Or fill the first element with the number 5?

`new int(grid_x)`, with round brackets, would create a *single* object, not an array, and specify the initial value.

There's no way to allocate an array with `new` *and* initialise them with a (non-zero) value. You'll have to assign the values after allocation.

> Line 4 fills the first element, how do I fill the rest?

You can use the *subscript operator* `[]` to access elements:

```
grid[0] = 34;  // Equivalent to: *(grid)   = 34
grid[1] = 42;  // Equivalent to: *(grid+1) = 42
// ...
grid[4] = 77;  // That's the last one: 5 elements from 0 to 4.
```

However, you usually don't want to juggle raw pointers like this; the burden of having to `delete[]` the array when you've finished with it can be difficult to fulfill. Instead, use the standard library. Here's one way to make a two-dimensional grid:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid(grid_x, std::vector<int>(grid_y));
grid[x][y] = 42; // for any x is between 0 and grid_x-1, y between 0 and grid_y-1
```

Or might be more efficient to use a single contiguous array; you'll need your own little functions to access that as a two-dimenionsal grid. Something like this might be a good starting point:

```
template <typename T>
class Grid {
public:
    Grid(size_t x, size_t y) : size_x(x), size_y(y), v(x*y) {}

    T       & operator()(size_t x, size_t y)       {return v[y*size_x + x];}
    T const & operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const {return v[y*size_x + x];}

private:
    size_t size_x, size_y;
    std::vector<T> v;
};

Grid grid(grid_x,grid_y);
grid(x,y) = 42;
```

Answer (score 11):

The default C++ way of creating a dynamic(ally resizable) array of `int` is:

```
std::vector<int> grid;
```

Don't play around with unsafe pointers and manual dynamic allocation when the standard library already encapsulates this for you.

To create a vector of 5 elements, do this:

```
std::vector<int> grid(5);
```

You can then access its individual elements using `[]`:

```
grid[0] = 34;
grid[1] = 42;
```

You can add new elements to the back:

```
// grid.size() is 5
grid.push_back(-42);
// grid.size() now returns 6
```

Consult [reference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to see all operations available on `std::vector`.

Comment: It is absolutely correct answer and one I'd gave myself for all cases, except for when the question was asked by those, who want to learn exactly about how raw arrays work or about how `std::vector` works internally (such as students or just curious). And looks like that is the case. I think that @MikeSeymour's answer is more appropriate here.

Comment: I hope that someone who wants to inspect standard libraries internals is more familiar with the c++ low level constructs.

Comment: @stefaanv That's exactly why I think that we must not forcibly push newcomer C++ programmers directly into Standard library convenient "wrappers", but give them a chance to go through pointer madness as we did it once. Even in C++14 era.

Comment: @Drop I have to disagree because when teaching e.g. Python, I wouldn't start with teaching how Python interacts with the CPU before using dictionaries even if there is a history in C++.  I would definitively go for streams, containers and strings before manual memory management.

Comment: @Drop I side with stefaanv here. If people start with pointers and dynamic arrays, they will always think in terms of these first, and not turn to "heavyweight `std` classes" when all they need is "a simple dynamic array." (I know *I* am guilty of this, and I've been learning to write proper C++ for years now).

Comment: @stefaanv , Angew Interesting, thank you for your opinions. It turns out that we could really do it in C# style, where they learn normal stuff first, and then unsafe code as advanced material. Sounds reasonable. Oh, and BTW, sorry for offtopic,

Answer (score 1):

> Should line 3 create an array with 5 elements? Or fill the first element with the number 5?

Create an array with 5 elements.

> Line 4 fills the first element, how do I fill the rest?

```
grid[n] = x;
```

Where `n` is the index of the element you want to set and `x` is the value.

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 allocates memory for 5 integers side by side in memory so that they can be accessed and modified by...

The bracket operator, `x[y]` is exactly equivalent to `*(x+y)`, so you could change Line 4 to `grid[0] = 34;` to make it more readable (this is why `grid[2]` will do the same thing as `2[grid]`!)

Answer (score 0):

```
int grid_x = 5 
int * grid; 
grid = new int[grid_x];
*grid = 34; 
cout << grid[0];

Should line 3 create an array with 5 elements? Or fill the first
element with the number 5?
```

Definitely the former. With the operator "new" you are allocating memory

> Line 4 fills the first element, how do I fill the rest?

Use operator `[]`, e.g.:

```
for int (i=0; i < grid_x; i++) { //Reset the buffer
  grid[i] = 0;
}
```

> Without line 4, line 5 reads "-842150451".

You are just reading uninitialized memory, it could be any value.

> I don't understand what is going on, I'm trying to create a 2
>   dimensional array using x and y values specified by the user, and then
>   fill each element one by one with numeric values also specified by the
>   user. My above code was an attempt to try it out with a 1 dimensional
>   array first.

Other users explained how to use vectors. If you have to set only once the size of your array, I usually prefer [boost::scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm)  which takes care of deleting when the variable goes out of scope.

For a two dimensional array of size not known at compile time, you need something a little bit trickier, like a scoped_array of scoped_arrays. Creating it will require necessarily a for loop, though.

```
using boost::scoped_array;
int grid_x;
int grid_y;
///Reading values from user...
scoped_array<scoped_array<int> > grid(new scoped_array<int> [grid_x]);
for (int i = 0; i < grid_x; i++)
  grid[i] = scoped_array<int>(new int[grid_y] );
```

You will be able then to access your grid elements as

```
grid[x][y];
```

**Note:**
It would work also taking scoped_array out of the game,

```
typedef int* p_int_t;
p_int_t* grid = new p_int_t [grid_x];
for (int i = 0; i < grid_x; i++)
  grid[i] = new int[grid_y];
```

but then you would have to take care of deletion at the end of the array's life, of ALL sub arrays.

Answer (score 0):

An array is simply a contiguous block of memory.  Therefore it has a starting address.

```
int * grid;
```

Is the C representation of the address of an integer, you can read the `*` as 'pointer'.  Since your array is an array of integers, the address of the first element in the array is effectively the same as the address of the array.  Hence line 3

grid = new int[grid_x];

allocates enough memory (on the heap) to hold the array and places its address in the `grid` variable.  At this point the content of that memory is whatever it was when the physical silicon was last used.  Reading from uninitialised memory will result in unpredictable values, hence your observation that leaving out line 4 results in strange output.

Remember that `*` pointer?  On line four you can read it as 'the content of the pointer' and therefore

```
*grid = 34;
```

means set the content of the memory pointed to by `grid` to the value 34.  But line 3 gave `grid` the address of the first element of the array.  So line 4 sets the first element of the array to be 34.

In C, arrays use a zero-based index, which means that the first element of the array is number 0 and the last is number-of-elements-in-the-array - 1.  So one way of filling the array is to index each element in turn to set a value to it.

```
for(int index = 0; index < grid_x; index++)
{
    grid[index] = 34;
}
```

Alternatively, you could continue to use a pointer to do the same job.

```
for(int* pointerToElement = grid; 0 < grid_x; grid_x-- )
{
    // save 34 to the address held by the pointer
    /// and post-increment the pointer to the next element.
    *pointerToElement++ = 34;
}
```

Have fun with arrays and pointers, they consistently provide a huge range of opportunities to spend sleepless hours wondering why your code doesn't work, PC reboots, router catches fire, etc, etc.